# Passing and calling a function from one service to the another

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I wrote a function that will get and update what I need.

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateWellFile(IEnumerable<AttachedFileListView> files, string wellId)
    {
        var updateFiles = await _attachedFileRepo.GetAllQueryable().Where(af => af.WellId == wellId).ToListAsync();

        
        if (files == null)
        {
            throw new ServiceException("File Not Found.");
        }
       foreach(var file in files)
        {
            var updateFile = updateFiles.SingleOrDefault(af => af.Id == file.Id);
           
            updateFile.Category = file.Category;
            _attachedFileRepo.Update(updateFile);

        }
        await _attachedFileRepo.CommitAsync();

        return true;
       
    }
```

This is in my AttachedFile Interface

```
 public interface IAttachedFileService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<AttachedFileListView>> GetWellAttachedFiles(string wellId);
    Task<string> SaveFile(IFormFile file, string wellId, string userId);
    Task<IEnumerable<string>> SaveFiles (IEnumerable<IFormFile> files, string wellId, string userId);
    Task<bool> UpdateWellFile(IEnumerable<AttachedFileListView> files, string wellId);
    Task<AttachedFile> GetFile(string fileId);
    Task<string> DeleteFile(string fileId);
}
```

Now I need to pass this updateWellFile function into the WellService and call it so I added it to the service but it is throwing this error

[image: Well Service]

here is the well service and I added the "accountservice" so I am not sure what else it needs

[image]

Comment: the wellservice is implementing iwellservice, so you need to define updatewellfile function as what iwellservice needed.

Comment: How would you code that out? Sorry I am a bit lost in the relationships here, this is what I thought I was doing here  IAttachedFileService fileService,

Comment: 24 dependencies?? This service is doing too much.

Comment: Under what situation requires you to implement iwellservice? is it because there are other services that are expecting wellservice to be injected? I mean how do u actually use the updatewellfile function? more description will be helpful. And yeah the injected services just a little bit too much.

Comment: thanks @LevananGan! The more I looked at your questions I had an epiphany that I may be over thinking this a bit. The solution was to simply pass in the parameters I needed from my function in AttachedFileService and I wouldn't need it in the interface at all. So my solution looked like this: 

await _attachedFileService.UpdateWellFile(well.Files, updateWell.Id);